# Bootable partition of an usb hard-disk with AOMEI Partition Assistant - Windows 8

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, boot-partition

I'd like to create a bootable partition of an usb hard disk. I created a partition and after I runned AOMEI partition assistant where I clicked on Windows to go creator. When I select the partition, the software says that usb devices with gpt partition are not supported. How could I solve this problem without touching others partitions?

Thank you.